# Disable readonly to text box onclicking the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have used "readonly" attribute to the textbox which makes the textbox non editable and may i know how to disable the readonly attribute on clicking the button. can we do this by using any script ?

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="" value="update" onclick="" />
```

Comment: jQuery or JavaScript, What are you using?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can do two things:

- Remove the [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-readonly) (case insensitive) attribute, using [`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.removeAttribute)
- Set the [`readOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties) (case sensitive) property to `false`

HTML:

```
<input id="myInput"  type="text"  readonly="readonly" /><br />
<input id="myButton" type="submit" value="update" />
```

JS (option 1): [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/343Rb/)]

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('myInput').removeAttribute('readonly');
};
```

JS (option 2): [[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/343Rb/1/)]

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('myInput').readOnly = false;
};
```

Comment: Is it necessary to include the code above inside the <script></script> tag?

Answer (score 5):

Well, to be simple! You can use jQuery to remove this attribute (jQuery would be simple, you can do this using JS too). Here is the code for that:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
  $('input[type=text]').removeAttr('readonly');
})
```

https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `readOnly` property of element to `false`

You can use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementByid), it reference to the element by its ID

*HTML*, Here I have added id to elements

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" name="" value="" readonly="readonly"/><br/>
<input type="submit" id="myButton"  name="" value="update" />
```

*JavaScript*, Here you can see `readOnly` property to false.

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById('myTextBox').readOnly =false;
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/DPcZV/)

Additionally, I would suggest you to use `'type="button"'` instead of `type="submit"`