# How to edit HTML (remove readonly) and type in input box using JS Executor?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver

This is the piece of HTML code on the particular page:

```
<input size="24" autocomplete="off" id="sch-555-et" 
name="./schimage" class="x-form-text x-form-field 
x-trigger-noedit" readonly="" style="width: 263px;" type="text">
```

It allows to browse image and refrains user to type in. I am told to skip the browsing part as it is error-prone also it isn't part of manual or automation tests.

I know how to type using JS Executor (https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/javascriptexecutor-selenium-webdriver/) but don't know how to edit HTML and then type.

**Edit:**
I don't know how my question is duplicate of [Disable readonly to text box onclicking the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609012/disable-readonly-to-text-box-onclicking-the-button)

Anyways I tried:

```
public JavascriptExecutor executeJS() {
    JavascriptExecutor jsexec = (JavascriptExecutor).driver;
    return jsexec;
}

executeJS().executeScript("document.getElementById('sch-555-et').removeAttribute('readonly')");
```

but it didn't remove "readonly" and element remain un-editable.

I tried to automate this page http://jsfiddle.net/343Rb/ also, and here it is giving error

1. `Cannot set property 'readOnly' of null` when trying to set value of readonly as null.
2. `Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null` when trying to remove readonly.

I am using Windows, Java, Selenium, Maven and TestNg

Comment: @downvoter anything wrong with the question, it's formatting? Unnecessary downvotes keep away genuine responses.

Comment: It's probably because this is a simple JavaScript question, wrapped up in "I'm using Selenium".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 This clearly isn't a javascript question. It's a question about how to edit a DOM which is being accessed through Selenium.

Comment: @DavidKnipe JavaScript Executor... executes JavaScript. Normal JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable readonly to text box onclicking the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609012/disable-readonly-to-text-box-onclicking-the-button)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `value` property to simulate typing. This will work even if the readonly attribute is present. But if you do want to remove the attribute, use [Element.removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).

```js
var el = document.getElementById('sch-555-et');

// Note: you can edit the value even if the readonly attribute is present.
el.removeAttribute('readonly');

el.value = 'Edited';
```

```html
<input size="24" autocomplete="off" id="sch-555-et" 
name="./schimage" class="x-form-text x-form-field 
x-trigger-noedit" readonly="" style="width: 263px;" type="text">
```

Comment: Seems this is I want. Once I make this HTML enable to accept text, I will use JS executor and start typing. How can I run your code in between my Selenium script?